# Are snowflake and grequests compatible? Why are crashes happening when querying and processing data in a loop?

Tags: python, asynchronous, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a snowflake db with 200,000+ records. I am reading a few thousand records from snowflake at a time in a loop using the python executor, and then making http calls using the data as payloads with grequests. Sometimes the code is working, and sometimes it is crashing with the error below when it has to retrieve more data from snowflake during one of the loop iterations:

```
 gevent.exceptions.LoopExit: This operation would block forever
```

I haven't been able to understand what is causing this from reading about gevent. The structure of my code basically is along the lines of:

```
results = []
query_text = 'SELECT * FROM PAYLOADS'
call_snowflake_db(query_text)
rs = (grequests.post(url, headers=header, data=data) for payload in payload_list)
rs_map = grequests.map(rs)
for response in rs_map:
    results.extend(response.json())
```

I would really appreciate any advice on how to do this efficiently using grequests, and what this error means